# How does nohup work?

Tags: linux, process, nohup

What is performed behind the scenes when a program runs with nohup?

Is the PID of the parent process being changed?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I understood that nohup (and disown) causes that SIGHUP is not sent to the process if the parent process receives it. Does it mean that it is equivalent to handling SIGHUP (and actually ignore it)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  Voting to migrate to Super User, although the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site would also be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use the source, Luke!](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/nohup.c)

(Extra characters added to keep the new answer length rules happy.)

Answer (score 6):

It is equivalent to setting the `SIGHUP` handler to `SIG_IGN`, ie.

```
signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: POSIX specifies that for execve signals whose handlers are either SIG_IGN or SIG_DFL are left unchanged: that is, an ignored signal is still ignored after an execve.There is a clear utility to being able to ignore signals across execve: that's how the nohup utility works.  commented by ianlancetaylor at a go issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20479

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia article about nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) explains it pretty well.