# How do I know if a bash script is running with nohup?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nohup

I have a script to process records in some files, it usually takes 1-2 hours. When it's running, it prints a progress of number of records processed.

Now, what I want to do is: when it's running with `nohup`, I don't want it to print the progress; it should print progress only when it run manually.

My question is how do I know if a bash script is running with `nohup`?

Suppose the command is `nohup myscript.sh &`. In the script, how do I get the `nohup` from command line? I tried to use `$0`, but it gives `myscript.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if STDOUT is associated with a terminal:

```
[ -t 1 ]
```

Comment: Note that this check the terminal, not if it is running under nohup. If you run `myscript.sh > out.txt` this check will fail too. (I didn't downvote you)

Answer (score 9):

Checking for file redirections is not robust, since `nohup` can be (and often is) used in scripts where stdin, stdout and/or stderr are already explicitly redirected.

Aside from these redirections, the only thing `nohup` does is [ignore the `SIGHUP` signal](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/nohup/nohup.c.html) (thanks to [Blrfl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3881916/580412) for the link.)

So, really what we're asking for is a way to detect if `SIGHUP` is being ignored.  In linux, the signal ignore mask is exposed in `/proc/$PID/status`, [in the least-significant bit of the `SigIgn` hex string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85365/10495).

Provided we know the pid of the bash script we want to check, we can use `egrep`.  Here I see if the current shell is ignoring `SIGHUP` (i.e. is "nohuppy"):

```
$ egrep -q "SigIgn:\s.{15}[13579bdf]" /proc/$$/status && echo nohuppy || echo normal
normal
$ nohup bash -c 'egrep -q "SigIgn:\s.{15}[13579bdf]" /proc/$$/status && echo nohuppy || echo normal'; cat nohup.out
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
nohuppy
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, but not really portable would be to do a readlink on `/proc/$$/fd/1` and test if it ends with nohup.out.

Assuming you are on the `pts0` terminal (not really relevant, just to be able to show the result):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(readlink /proc/$$/fd/1) =~ nohup.out$ ]]; then
    echo "Running under hup" >> /dev/pts/0
fi
```

But the traditional approach to such problems is to test if the output is a terminal:

```
[ -t 1 ]
```

Comment: If you run myscript.sh > out.txt this check will fail.

Comment: Can you show how this would look as a complete if/else?

Answer (score 1):

You can either check if the parent pid is 1:

```
if [ $PPID -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo "Parent pid=1  (runing via nohup)" 
else
    echo "Parent pid<>1 (NOT running via nohup)"                                             
fi
```

or if your script ignores the SIGHUP signal (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638712/1011025):

```
if egrep -q "SigIgn:\s.{15}[13579bdf]" /proc/$$/status ; then
    echo "Ignores SIGHUP (runing via nohup)" 
else
    echo "Doesn't ignore SIGHUP (NOT running via nohup)"                                             
fi
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer doesn't get more upvotes - checking $PPID is very simple and works perfectly for my use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Check STDOUT is a good idea. I just find another way to do it. That is to test tty. 
test tty -s check its return code. If it's 0 , then it's running on a terminal; if it's 1 then it's running with nohup.

Comment: actually, you are doing the exact same thing tty -s  checks if stdout is a terminal (see: http://ss64.com/bash/tty.html) and -t 1 is the same (see: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)